# Python script hangs when MySQL connector loses connection due to internet or wifi drop

Tags: python, mysql, connection, timeout, dropout

I have a script in python running on a raspberry pi zero w+ that is constantly reading some sensors and logging the data in a MySQL database. The database lives in a server that is separate from the pi and is accessed over the internet.
Whenever the internet connection and/or the wifi get interrupted, the script just hungs and the execution seems to continue, but it gets infinitely dead until stopped with Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Z.

I have tried to use

```
try:
     cursor.execute(query)
     XXXX 
except:
     pass
```

to avoid the script crashing in case the cursor was closed or faulty.
I have also tried to put an

```
  try:
    if(conection.is_connected()):
         cursor.execute(query)
         XXXX 
  except:
         pass
```

But instead of raising an exception, the script just hangs and needs to be stopped.

I also tried with setting connection timeouts, with the same results.

Any ideas?

Cheers
J

Answer (score 1):

Solved!
I changed the connector from mysql connector to PyMySQL, which has read_timeout and write_timeout as connection parameters, raising an exception when the connection is lost and the timeout has passed. I could not find this functionality with the official MySQL connector.

Cheers
J